# how to diagnose Apache2.4 service error 7024 Incorrect function

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

System:

- Windows 10 x64 (enterprise computer with some restrictions)
- Apache 2.4 64-bit
- Python 3.7.1 64-bit
- mod_wsgi (built today from github using python setup.py install)

I am working on getting an Apache server with Python on a Windows machine and I have the server configured correctly in order to get the `Hello World!` example from [mod_wsig documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#wsgi-application-script-file) working.

If I simply launch `C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe`, this works and I see Hello World at http://localhost:5000/

Then I wanted to get it running as a service, so I call

`httpd.exe -k install`

In the ApacheMonitor I start the new Apache2.4 service but I get a failed to start error.  In the Windows system event log it says `Event ID: 7024` with a service specific error: `Incorrect function`.

When I run `httpd.exe -k start -n "Apache2.4" -t` it says `Syntax OK`

What I can't find is any more information about the service error.  Nothing populates in the `error.log` file and I don't know where else to look, and I am asking for any further information on how to diagnose this.

Before I started configuring Apache to use mod_wsgi, launching the service was successful, so this happened after doing that, and I haven't configured anything else at this point.

Comment: In your httpd.conf, put `LogLevel debug` and make sure `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` are defined to an existing path on your window.  Restart.  Hopefully you will get more detailed errors with debug logs.

Comment: thanks I appreciate the suggestion.  I tried many LogLevel settings and both Logs are correctly created.  I suppose it might just be something specific to my machine, but I don't really know how to probe it any further

Comment: The logs are created, but do they contain any hint that might help?  Event logs show nothing more?  I did some research, but in most cases it was ports issues, but the errors were quite clear when put in debug level.

Comment: Nothing is populated in the logs in this instance even though the files are there and populated when httpd is just called from the command line

Comment: Wow...  does the service definition force which configuration file to use (i.e. use the `-f` argument)?  I wonder if it uses the same configuration as when you run it from cmd.

Comment: I haven’t tried but for both I was using the default conf/http.conf. I suppose I could try and see if with a different conf it works

Comment: Did you fix this error? I get the same error as you.

Comment: No I gave up and switched to Linux

Comment: For the record: Switching loglevel in httpd.conf helped in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the Command Prompt move to the apache/bin folder and type

```
>httpd -t
```

This will give you more information about the error preventing Apache from start.

Comment: httpd -t only stated that syntax is ok, whatever that means. However, running httpd (rather then trying to start the service) told me: `AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443.`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after updating my httpd.conf file.  The problem was that my final xml tag in httpd.conf was unclosed </directory without the closing >.

Answer (score 0):

This days I was facing the same situation, windows 10, apache24, django app, python3.8, failing to start as service, service events showing error 7024...

So, after a lot of struggling and research, I would like to add my solution even this is an old question.

The solution was to add two environment variables, no in httpd.conf, not in python code/conf but at SO level (windows > environment variables)

> PYTHONHOME = c:\your\path\to\installed\python

> PYTHONPATH = c:\your\path\to\installed\virtualenv

And magic! apache now works as service and the django app is always available on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error as the OP and had the same challenge, i.e. even with the most verbose logging there was nothing to indicate the problem.

The two pieces of information I did have:

1. When running `httpd.exe` from the command line, everything worked normally.
2. When trying to call `httpd.exe` from the service, it failed to start.

So on a hunch I reconfigured the service to not log on as `LocalSystem`, and instead to log on as my NT user account (which has the logon as a service setting already enabled).  With this change, the service started normally.

I haven't troubleshot any further at this point.  (I have ruled out file access privileges as the problem, because all file paths involved are set to provide full privileges for Everyone.)  But anyway, this was a simple and easily attempted fix.